# How to make the middle of the table become thick like the example image two above

Tags: html, css, svg

This is my current table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBJA4.png)

I want my table to become this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBsq5.png)

This is my Table Code

```html
   <table>
    <thead>
    <td><input type="text" name="treat1" style="width: 80px"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="treat2"style="width: 80px"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="treat3"style="width: 80px"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="treat4"style="width: 80px"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="treat5"style="width: 80px"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="treat6"style="width: 80px"></td>
    
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
    
               <td style="width: 5%;" ><svg class="teeth" id="svg"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="premolar-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><svg class="teeth" id="svg2"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="premolar-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><svg class="teeth" id="svg3"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="premolar-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><svg class="teeth" id="svg4"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="premolar-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><svg class="teeth" id="svg5"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="premolar-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    
    <td style="width: 5%;"><svg class="teeth" id="svg6"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
         <g id="incisor-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="incisal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 112.5 75 112.5" fill="white" />    
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 187.5 226 112.5" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 187.5 225 187.5" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 112.5 75 187.5" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    
    
    </tbody>
    
     <br>
           <thead>
    <td><input type="text" name="treat7" style="width: 80px"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="treat8"style="width: 80px"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="treat9"style="width: 80px"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="treat10"style="width: 80px"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="treat11"style="width: 80px"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="treat12"style="width: 80px"></td>
    
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
    
               <td style="width: 5%;" ><svg class="teeth" id="svg7"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="premolar-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><svg class="teeth" id="svg8"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="premolar-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><svg class="teeth" id="svg9"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="premolar-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><svg class="teeth" id="svg10"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="premolar-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><svg class="teeth" id="svg11"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
        <g id="premolar-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    
    <td style="width: 5%;"><svg class="teeth" id="svg12"
     width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!-- upper right 8 -->
         <g id="incisor-group">
            <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="incisal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
            <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 112.5 75 112.5" fill="white" />    
            <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 187.5 226 112.5" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 187.5 225 187.5" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 112.5 75 187.5" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
            <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </svg></td>
    
    
    </tbody>
    
    <style type="text/css">
            .teeth{
              width: 75px;
              height: auto;
            }
    
         
    </style>
    </table>
```

How to make the middle of the table become thick like the example image two above. Can anyone help me how to do this part. My Concern of this problem to make the middle line of the the table thick. Is it possible to make? Sorry guy's i'm just a beginner.

Comment: Simply add border-left:5px solid #000; to the td's where you want the thicker border. Not sure wether I understood your exact problem.

Comment: Thank's sir @RNH

Comment: I copied this to answers so you can accept and close this topic. Please try to do a quick google search next time, this was a basic question. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** 
Simply add `border-left:5px solid #000;` to the td's where you want the thicker border.

**Note:** this is **basic** html/css knowledge. Please do a quick google search next time.